# Two way binding on attributes angularjs

Tags: data-binding, angularjs-directive, attributes

The attributes value is not updating on two way binding on attributes. Do I need to watch on attribute?
I created a simple two way binding. If I change the minValue after the directive is rendered, It doesn't update the new minValue.

```
angular.app('revMgmtApp', []);
angular.module('revMgmtApp').controller('testCtrl', testCtrl);

function testCtrl() {
    var vm = this;
    vm.counter = 1;
    vm.minValue = 10;
};



angular.module('revMgmtApp').directive('testDir', function ($compile) {

    var calController = function () {
        var vm = this;
        vm.localOpen = function ($event) {
            $event.preventDefault();
            $event.stopPropagation();
            vm.opened = true;
        }
    }

    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        scope: {
            ngModel: '=',
            minValue: '=',
        },
        replace: true,
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs, modelCtrl) {
            debugger;
            var el = '<div><span>';
            el += '<input type="number" ng-model="vm.ngModel"  ';

            if (scope.vm.minValue != null) {
                el += " min='" + scope.vm.minValue + "' ";
            }
            el += "/>";
            var el1 = $compile(el)(scope);
            elem.replaceWith(el1);

        },
        controller: calController,
        bindToController: true,
        controllerAs: 'vm',
    }

})

    <div ng-app="revMgmtApp" ng-controller="testCtrl as ctrl">
    <p>
        Enter min counter <input type="number" ng-model="ctrl.minValue" />
    </p>

    <test-dir ng-model="ctrl.counter" min-value="ctrl.minValue"></test-dir>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In answer to your question.  Yes, you need a watch on the attributes and a function that updates the value.

```
scope.$watch(attrs.testDir, function(value) {
    //set value here
    //call update value here
  });
```

I would follow this example in [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/4t3OjEdSKjjXJnvY6Gfw?p=preview), or here under ["Creating a Directive that Manipulates the DOM"](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)

But, you might be making it a little more complicated then you need to.  It's an isolated scope, so we will add the scope variables we want access to as attributes in the html.

For clarity, I'm going to rename attributes in the directive html to:

```
<test-dir mymodel="ctrl.counter" mymin="ctrl.minValue"></test-dir>
```

Then, on the scope, define the attributes that holds the scope variable you will be using.

```
scope: {
        mymodel: '=mymodel',
        myminval: '=mymin',
    },
```

Then instead of "**link:**" use a template.

```
template: '<div><span><input ng-model="mymodel" min="myminval"/></span></div>';
```

This way you are only **binding** to the values you care about.

Comment: I used link because whatever attribute I pass to the directive, I want to apply to the input.

Comment: When you use two way binding with the template, you don't have to worry about any additional watch because the value is bound.  If you change the value at any point it will update the template value.  You also get the added benefit of more readable code, rather then splitting the element apart with logic and concatenations.  But you could just keep it the way you have and add the watch, like the example in the plunker code.

Comment: Thanks CodeBob. Only issue with template is I want to pass as many as attribute to the directive and apply to the input field. I will keep watch on attributes.